# Assets not fetched on cpanel server

Tags: javascript, html, css, server, cpanel

I'm trying to work on cpanel before hosting my own website. And I'm very much new to this. After uploading my files on cpanel, I am getting the error and the assets folder is not read & my css & js files are not found. On localhost everything is working fine but on cpanel its not working.
I keep getting this error `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

I tired looking for a solution, but most of them were regarding localhost, but the files are working on my localhost but not on cpanel.

Can anybody help me please.

Console errors:

[image: Console errors]

Network JS headers:

[image: Network JS headers]

Comment: check if you are able to access assets in the browser to see that open the url of asset. issue might be due to wrong path

Comment: @shubhamjha I cant access the files via browser url too, getting the same error. But the path is correct. The same path works perfectly on my localhost.

Comment: if you can’t access your public file via browser then there must be wrong base path, or there might be permission issues

Comment: @shubhamjha The base path seems fine to me because the html is loading but not the css & js. How can i change the permission in cpanel ?

Comment: what is path of html file and css and js file add on the question

Comment: @shubhamjha the path for the css & js files are https://perlmindz.rf.gd/indiahousing/admin_assets
In admin_assets all the css & js have been transfered, the if i replace the domain name with localhost & run it on localhost, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the problem was the domain name, which direct the http request to the assets folder, but here I was using a free domain name that i got from infinityfree. And when i tried running the same link on a different cpanel with purchased domain name, it's loads up just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).